# How to completely remove MacOS (Ventura) from Macbook Pro 2019 with T2, and install Linux?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, efi, bootable-disk, t2

**System**: Macbook Pro 2019, Intel, T2, 16 GB RAM, No USB port (Using VIVA USB hub), Ventura 13.6.5

**Issues**: (1) Hash Volume Mismatch (2) Not re-installing MacOS (3) Bootable USB Drive is NOT showing up

**Question**: How can I completely wipe out MacOS, and install Linux?

Comment: We might need some more details about what you tried so far, which instructions you followed and where/how it failed to work.

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/LinuxOnLate2011.md) won't help you much I'm afraid; I installed Ubuntu on a 2011 model MBP, and it still runs great! To their shame, Apple has made recycling their hardware more difficult than it need be. Good luck to you!